# insertRow is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

```
function create_table(id){
var table = document.getElementById(id);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 

var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);  
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
    element1.style.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";


    element1.setAttribute("type","text");
    element1.setAttribute("size","1");
    element1.setAttribute("name",seq);
    element1.setAttribute("id",seq);
    
    element1.setAttribute("value",val_sq );

    element1.setAttribute("readOnly","true");

    cell1.appendChild(element1);
}
```

If I call this function it shows TypeError: insertRow is not a function. I tried to get some answers from search engine.But no use. Please help me to find out

Comment: `insertRow` will work fine if called on the right sort of element. Make sure you're passing in the right parameter to `create_table`.

Comment: if i have 4 more rows then it will works fine. but i have 1ly one row in existing table then it throws this error inser row is not a function

Comment: Create a MCVE so that others can reproduce the problem too

Comment: `create table`  i didint use. i am creating new tr in existing table